# PyQt's QMainWindow closeEvent is never called

Tags: python, events, pyqt4

I'm using pyqt4 in python.
When I close the QMainWindow window , its not handled by `closeEvent` method. 
Please someone tell me what is wrong with this code:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(277, 244)
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtGui.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
    def closeEvent(self,event):
        result = QtGui.QMessageBox.question(self,
                      "Confirm Exit...",
                      "Are you sure you want to exit ?",
                      QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes| QtGui.QMessageBox.No)
        event.ignore()

        if result == QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes:
         event.accept()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtGui.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `closeEvent` is a method of `QMainwindow`, but you're trying to use it from your own `Ui_MainWindow` class. Try this instead:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui


class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setupUi()

    def setupUi(self):
        self.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        self.resize(277, 244)
        self.statusbar = QtGui.QStatusBar()
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        self.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

    def closeEvent(self,event):
        result = QtGui.QMessageBox.question(self,
                      "Confirm Exit...",
                      "Are you sure you want to exit ?",
                      QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes| QtGui.QMessageBox.No)
        event.ignore()

        if result == QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes:
            event.accept()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWindow = MainWindow()
    mainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

If you want to keep as much of your structure as possible, try this:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(277, 244)
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtGui.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
        MainWindow.show()


class MyWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def closeEvent(self,event):
        result = QtGui.QMessageBox.question(self,
                      "Confirm Exit...",
                      "Are you sure you want to exit ?",
                      QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes| QtGui.QMessageBox.No)
        event.ignore()

        if result == QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes:
            event.accept()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = MyWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. Yes the code running fine. How to reach this problem with my given code?

Answer (score -3):

This is my solution,

```
    def closeEvent(self, e):
        close = QMessageBox.question(
            self,
            "Close Application",
            "Are you sure?",
            QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No,
            QMessageBox.No
        )
        e.ignore()
        if close == QMessageBox.Yes:
            e.accept()
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes

Comment: This function is identical to the one in the original question

Comment: This answer is essentially a duplicate of the accepted answer, on a > 6 year old question. Do not post duplicate answers. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/27790139)